# See Hive UDF function name to class mappings

Tags: hive

On my hive database there are many custom UDFs and I can see them being used in many queries.

in the source control, I can see many classes which extend UDF.

but the names of classes and the UDF functions don't match.

How can I find out the list of custom UDFs and the classes to which they map to?

I tried `show functions` but this shows all functions even operators like `+`.

I don't need OOB functions. I need only custom UDFs and I need the class names to which they map to.

I am using cloudera 5.4.1

Comment: To see which jars have been added to the classpath you can use : list jars command

Comment: not just the jars. function names and class names